# Using user-defined variable from select statement in its where clause

Tags: mysql

I have this select statement working fine:

```
SELECT 
  pre, dict.char, post, score
  , (SELECT @res := MatchPre(pre, 'test') AS var) AS mpre 
FROM dict;
```

It returns all of the data properly, with the result from MatchPre in a column labeled "mpre".  However, I want to only get results where mpre > 0.  So, logically, I tried this:

```
SELECT 
  pre, dict.char, post, score
  , (SELECT @res := MatchPre(pre, 'test') AS var) AS mpre 
FROM dict 
WHERE mpre > 0;
```

But to no avail.  I've tried swapping "WHERE mpre > 0" with "WHERE @res > 0", "WHERE @res.mpre > 0", "WHERE mpre.@res > 0", etc, but it either throws an error or returns an empty result set despite the original where-less query giving rows with mpre values greater than 0.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  pre, dict.char, post, score
  , (SELECT @res := MatchPre(pre, 'test') AS var) AS mpre 
FROM dict 
HAVING mpre > 0;
```

You cannot use aliases in a `where` clause.
You will have to use a `having` clause or put the select with the alias inside another outer select.

This is because when the `where` clause is run, the alias is not yet evaluated.
The `having` run **after** all the `select`,`where`, `group by`, `from` and `joins` are finished and does not suffer this limitation.
Having cannot use an index though.
If you want to use an index use a sub-select.

```
SELECT sub.* FROM
  (SELECT 
     pre, dict.char, post, score
     , (SELECT @res := MatchPre(pre, 'test') AS var) AS mpre 
   FROM dict ) sub
 WHERE sub.mpre > 0
```